# Sending E-mails in a schedule that changes with time

Tags: apex

I have got two scheduled apex class running.

It sends two E-mails and two Texts twice a day.

1) I wish to send only one E-mail and text after 3 days.

2) After 7 days E-mail and text twice a week.

3) After 14 days once a week.

Q) What would be the best way to implement this.

I was thinking having a custom field and checking that. Is it possible to set something like this in CRON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Process Builder with `Email Alerts` and `InvocableMethods` to schedule these kind of items one after the other.

Using custom fields with your current Apex Jobs is also a good way to go (keep track of last datetime sent, next datetime to send, etc)